# HtAccess Redirect with regular expression

Tags: .htaccess, zend-framework, redirect, seo

Do anyone know on how to set a redirection for this url :

old url : domain.com/123-name-123-nmae.html
new url : domain.com/name-123-nmae.html

I want the old url to new one. There are thousands of urls on this same pattern , so I require the redirection to be done using a regular expression .

Is there any regular expression for it.

thanks in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^[0-9]+-(.+?\.html)$ /$1 [L,NE.R=301]
```